# Is there a json schema file for Azure Devops Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have exported my pipeline from Azure Devops. This results in a json file I can import to create a new build definition. Is there a schema definition that defines this file. I would like to edit it (using VS) and a schema serve as documentation-instead of hacking it.

Comment: More easy is to move to yaml builds. I don't think there is a schema for the json :/

Answer (score 5):

There's [yamlschema endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/yamlschema/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) in Azure DevOps REST API that returns schema for YAML pipeline:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/yamlschema?api-version=5.1
```

Seems like this is where [azure pipelines extension](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-vscode/blob/master/service-schema.json) takes it from.

Comment: Better to use this version instead of the one from GitHub if your organization/pipeline use custom tasks that the default schema will complain about

Answer (score 3):

I use vscode and I'm trying out the [yaml extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml). However, I found there is also an [azure pipeline extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azure-devops.azure-pipelines), but the yaml extension is more popular.

In order for me to get azure pipelines working on the yaml extension, I was able to find the json schema that azure pipelines used [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-vscode/blob/master/service-schema.json). I referenced using the raw file, but there are still bugs here and there.

Comment: The azure pipeline extension is better in this regard since it parses the YAML schema based on the pipeline syntax. So, it can validate actual key words. In general YAML extensions it is not provided.

Answer (score 2):

On the https://www.schemastore.org/json/ there are a lot of schemas, and especially for [Azure Devops Pipelines](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-vscode/v1.174.2/service-schema.json)

Answer (score 0):

The file [tasks.schema.json](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/master/tasks.schema.json) seems a schema definition for the tasks in pipeline. And this repo(https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks) includes examples on how we write tasks which will help you write other tasks which can be uploaded to your account or server.

Comment: thanks, but what I need is the json schema that defines a build pipeline.

Comment: @jlo-gmail, at the moment there is no json schema that defines a build/release pipeline, but there is [YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema).